# Extract array of specific member values from array of class instances in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've found lots of information for converting whole classes to hashes, and selecting from arrays.  I can't seem to word my question correctly for Google to give me a useful response.  Let's say I have a class with a member variable

```
class class_name_here
  attr_reader :var_name_here
  attr_reader :another_var_name
end
```

Then I have an array of this class

```
array_of_class_instances
```

How do I extract an array of var_name_here values for the entire array?  For example, if in instance 1 of class_name_here, the value of var_name_here is "String 1", and in instance 2 it is "Hello, world", the output I want is ["String 1", "Hello, world"].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map mehod:

```
array_of_class_instances.map(&:var_name_here)
```

If this is an ActiveRecord model:

```
array_of_class_instances.pluck(:var_name_here)
```

Comment: Your middle method isn't Rails-specific. Core Ruby will do that too.

Comment: Thanks, map is definitely what I couldn't find.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - use `map`

```
array_of_var_name_here = array_of_class_instances.map(&:var_name_here)
```

Note that the `&:var_name_here` syntax is just a neat way of saying "the block consisting of the method `var_name_here`. It's equivalent to

```
array_of_var_name_here = array_of_class_instances.map { |ci| ci.var_name_here }
```

Answer (score 0):

One one often uses an `initialize` method in conjunction with an accessor:

```
class X
  attr_reader :var_name1
  attr_reader :var_name2
  def initialize(var_name1, var_name2)
    @var_name1 = var_name1
    @var_name2 = var_name2
  end
end
```

and then:

```
x = X.new(:cat, :hat)
y = X.new(:dog, :log)

array_of_class_instances = [x, y]
i = array_of_class_instances.first
i.var_name1 # => :cat 
i.var_name2 # => :hat
```

which you can put into an array if you wish.  Alternatively,

```
class X
  attr_reader :var_name1
  attr_reader :var_name2
end
```

and then:

```
x = X.new
x.var_name1 = :cat
x.var_name2 = :hat
y = X.new
y.var_name1 = :dog
y.var_name2 = :log

array_of_class_instances = [x, y]
i = array_of_class_instances.first
i.var_name1 # => :cat 
i.var_name2 # => :hat
```